# Insert php nested array into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, multidimensional-array

what is the optimal way for me to insert and array of 1000 lines and 10 columns each into a mysql table below is how i display it so it would be a similar construct but i need some directions

```
foreach ($stack as $val) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($val as $no) {
       print " <td>$no</td>\n";}
 print "</tr>\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows with a single insert as follows :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

look at [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create the values string from your array

Answer (score 1):

Better way to insert thousands of data into DB is to use implode function [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing u got something like this

`$stack = array("man1" => array("name"=>"ik", "class"=>"highskl", "age"=> "12"),"man1" => array("name"=>"ijk", "class"=>"higkl", "age"=> "13"));`

and you want to insert them into a table, try and use the table fields as index for the inner arrays then adjust the code to look like this

```
    foreach ($stack as $entry => $value) {
$query = "INSERT INTO table set ";
foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
   $query .= $key ."= ".$val.",";}
 //use a string function to remove the last comma
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in Query ".$entry." ",mysql_error());
//this helps to track error..
}
```

Comment: sorry this came late...power failure!